# How to get index of $scope.variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have $scope

```
Object.keys($scope)

[...
11 : "clientSelectedRepeat"
12:"countrySelectedRepeat"
13:"initCountry"
14: "getType"
...]
```

if i know name of variable How to get index of $scope.getType ?

Comment: why do you need the index?  `$scope` isn't designed for you to work with properties in that manner.

Comment: @Claies i want to get name of variable having $scope.getType. Get string name of variable

Comment: what does that mean?  `getType` is a Property of `$scope`, what does "get name of variable having `$scope.getType`" even mean? you have a variable somewhere that is equal to `$scope.getType`?

Comment: @Claies more questions. don't understand? for what type in here then

Comment: I want to help, as I am sure others do as well.  However, your question doesn't make sense.  If you don't want to try and take the time to explain what you are doing and improve the question so that you can get an answer that's fine, but don't expect an answer to a question that others can't make sense of.  see [ask].